# DateTime substracting days doesn't work

Tags: c#, datetime

I am using the following code in order to substract a day of the `DateTime` until I am getting Monday:

```
DateTime currentWeek = new DateTime(beginDate.Year, beginDate.Month, beginDate.Day);                
while (currentWeek.DayOfWeek.ToString() != "Monday")
{
    currentWeek.AddDays(-1);
    MessageBox.Show(currentWeek.Day.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(currentWeek.DayOfWeek.ToString());
}
```

`beginDate` is in the first run set to the current Date of `DateTime.Now`.

For me this loops forever, and the day of `currentWeek` always stays the same (29) even though I am substracting 1 everytime I am looping through.

I am already using another function that takes a `DateTime` and a `bool` Parameter, which does pretty much the same and works:

```
private void ErstenTagDerWocheAuswaehlen(DateTime date, bool anfangDerWoche = true)
{
    string wochentagName;
    int incrementor;
    if(anfangDerWoche == true)
    {
        wochentagName = "Monday";
        incrementor = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        wochentagName = "Friday";
        incrementor = 1;
    }

    while(date.DayOfWeek.ToString() != wochentagName)
    {                
        date = date.AddDays(incrementor);
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why the upper code doesn't work whilst the lower one does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to assign the resulting value, DateTime is immutable.

```
currentWeek = currentWeek.AddDays(-1);
```

---

About your 2nd question:

1. Use the enum for day of the week, do not try to convert a day of the week to a string for a comparison. The type is `DayOfWeek`.
2. Again, a `DateTime` is not mutable so you have to return a `DateTime` instance as you can't mutate the one that was passed in (*without passing it as `ref`*)

Code change

```
private DateTime ErstenTagDerWocheAuswaehlen(DateTime date, bool anfangDerWoche = true)
{
    System.DayOfWeek wochentagName;
    int incrementor;
    if(anfangDerWoche == true)
    {
        wochentagName = System.DayOfWeek.Monday;
        incrementor = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        wochentagName = System.DayOfWeek.Friday;
        incrementor = 1;
    }

    while(date.DayOfWeek != wochentagName)
    {                
        date = date.AddDays(incrementor);
    }
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Jesus, I compared these lines for more than 10 minutes or so, and didnt see that I missed the assignment, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` is an immutable struct, so you need to store the value returned from `AddDays()`:

```
var t2 = currentWeek.AddDays(-1);
```

Then use `t2`. The call to `AddDays()` doesn't actually change `currentWeek`.

Answer (score 2):

As `DateTime` is immutable, when using the `AddDays` it returns a new `DateTime` structure with the new information and does not change the given one.
Method documentation states:

> Returns a new System.DateTime that adds the specified number of days to the value of this instance.

You must assign it to a variable:

```
currentWeek = currentWeek.AddDays(-1);
```